# Why use two LSTM layers one after another?

Tags: keras, lstm

In the example on the Keras site, [seq2seq_translate.py](https://github.com/roatienza/Deep-Learning-Experiments/blob/master/keras/seq2seq/seq2seq_translate.py) on line 189, there is a LSTM layer after another (the first with `return_sequences=True`), but another example [lstm_seq2seq.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py) which does the same thing but letter-by-letter uses only one LSTM in the encoder. My code looks like:

```
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(encoder)
```

My question is why does the word-by-word version use two LSTM layers? And why is the return_sequences used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your first question:
It is because word-by-word NLP model is more complicated than letter-by-letter one, so it needs a more complex network (more hidden units) to be modeled suitably.

About your second question:
When you want to use two-staged LSTMs, the hidden sequence of first LSTM must be used as input of the second LSTM and the return_sequences option is used to do this.

Comment: Thanks @pythinker - I added some code to my question - so I've got the `return_sequences` and `return_state` around the right way?

Comment: @NicCottrell Yes, that is right, but note that inclusion of return_state is optional.

Comment: `return_state=False` by default though, so isn't it required for `state_h, state_c` to be returned?

Comment: @NicCottrell It is absolutely required for state_h and state_c to be returned but not for encoder_outputs.